# How to limit CPU usage by ansible-playbook, and any best practises?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I did a Lithmus test of the CPU usage on my AWS EC2 instance when ansible-playbook runs. I found to my surprise that the CPU usage peaks at 99%. I used Python's `psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)` for my Lithmus testing.

NOTE: My EC2 Linux box had 0% CPU utilization prior to running `ansible-playbook`.

```
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
99.0
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
98.0
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
88.8
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
91.8
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
99.0
>>> psutil.cpu_percent(interval=1)
99.0
```

I want to limit the CPU usage of `ansible-playbook` since I will be running it for live updates of production servers. How would I go about limiting the CPU usage by Ansible using any ***best practises***?

1. Should I use Linux `renice` for all Python processes?
2. Should I limit the CPU usage with Python or built-in Ansible options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the number of forks used when running ansible-playbook. Set the number to anything below the number of cores on the server

```
ansible-playbook -f 1
```

If that doesn't work, try using the cpulimit tool

```
apt-get install cpulimit
cpulimit -l 50 ansible-playbook -f 1
```

Comment: Thanks, nice one. I tried it but it doesn't have any impact, the CPU utilization by `ansible-playbook` is still hovering around 90-100%.

Comment: The other command should reduce the cpu usage if you don't have many cores